# Adding color gradient legend for visualizing the node centrality

Tags: osmnx

I am a beginner at using osmnx package in python. From the examples in https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/08-example-line-graph.ipynbin 
 I am trying to visualize network required from my project which is the railway network of country Denmark. I was able to visualize the node centrality values on the network with a color gradient. But I want to add a legend which shows the values and the corresponding color palette for better understanding rather than just saying the lowest values represented dark areas and vise versa. I have tried implementing legend functions from other packages but was unable to get the legend eventually. It is possible that there is a inbuilt function which I don't know about. It will be really helpful if one could give some suggestions for this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=pd.Series(node_centrality).sort_values(), columns=['cc'])
df['colors'] = ox.get_colors(n=len(df), cmap='inferno', start=0.2)
df = df.reindex(G.nodes())
nc = df['colors'].tolist()
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, bgcolor='k', node_size=30, node_color=nc, node_edgecolor='none', node_zorder=2,
                        edge_color='#555555', edge_linewidth=1.5, edge_alpha=1)
```

The implemented code is similar to the provided code in the examples but implemented for the railway network of Denmark.